# How to use textopenbullet character for the nested itemize lists?

Tags: lists

I will use \textopenbullit symbol for all secods level lists in my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}         
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\textopenbullet$}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize} 
\item Bla bla
     \begin{itemize} 
        \item Bla bla bla
        \item ...
     \end{itemize}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

But I get an error for every line with an list item:

> Command \textopenbullet unavailable in encoding OT1.

What is OT1 (I don't use this package) and how can I fix this problem?

(When I use for example  \renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$**\star**$}  always is good.)

Comment: @karlkoeller, with \usepackage{textcomp} I become another set of errors:
* Symbol font `TS1letters' is not defined. ...tSymbol{\textcapitalcompwordmark}{TS1}{23}
* Symbol font `TS1letters' is not defined. ...Symbol{\textascendercompwordmark}{TS1}{31}
* Symbol font `TS1letters' is not defined. ...extSymbol{\textquotestraightbase}{TS1}{13}
...

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `enumitem`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[itemize,2]{label=\textopenbullet}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla
     \begin{itemize}
        \item Bla bla bla
        \item ...
     \end{itemize}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

`\textopenbullet` is a *text* command defined by the `textcomp` package.

This package, for compatibility issues, has to be loaded *before* the `mathtext` package.

Also your definition should be

```
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\textopenbullet}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{cmap}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{mathtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\frenchspacing
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}

\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{\textopenbullet}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item Bla bla
     \begin{itemize}
        \item Bla bla bla
        \item ...
     \end{itemize}
\item aaa
\item bbb
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]